# AngularJS: Remove duplicate objects and reorder an array by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, foreach

I am using a json, this is the structure:

```
  { "variants": [
    { "capacity":"A", "color":"1" },
    { "capacity":"A", "color":"2" },
    { "capacity":"B", "color":"3" }
  ]};
```

Using `angular.forEach` or another method, I would like to display data no repeated, reordered it and related it by "capacity", something like this (a new array):

```
$scope.newArray = [
  { "capacity":"A", "color1":"1", "color2":"2" },
  { "capacity":"B", "color_1":"3" }
];
```

It is possible an angular way or simply javascript, I need help!

Comment: * Remove duplicate values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = { 'variants': [
      {'capacity': 'A','color': '1'},
      {'capacity': 'A','color': '2'},
      {'capacity': 'B','color': '3'},
]};

b = a.variants
c = b.reduce(function (prev, crt) {
  prev[crt.capacity] = (prev[crt.capacity] || [
  ]).concat(crt.color)
  return prev;
}, {})
// c is now {"A": ["1","2"], "B": ["3"]}

d = []
for (var name in c) {
  if (c.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    f = {
      'capacity': name
    }
    c[name].forEach(function (e) {
      f['color' + e] = e;
    })
    // f is {"capacity": "A", "color1": "1","color2": "2"}
    // and then {"capacity": "B", "color3": "3"}
    d = d.concat(f)
  }
}

// d is [{"capacity": "A", "color1": "1","color2": "2"},
//       {"capacity": "B", "color3": "3"}]
```